# Apache/httpd error: Invalid command 'WSGIPythonHome'

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

**ISSUE:**

My Apache/httpd server will not launch. `journalctl -xe` reveals:

```
Feb 27 01:50:12 localhost.localdomain httpd[4398]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 355 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Feb 27 01:50:12 localhost.localdomain httpd[4398]: Invalid command 'WSGIPythonHome', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Feb 27 01:50:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 27 01:50:13 localhost.localdomain kill[4399]: kill: cannot find process ""
Feb 27 01:50:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 27 01:50:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

`httpd -S` reveals:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 355 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'WSGIPythonHome', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

**SPECS**

- CentOS 7 (This is a virtual machine running on an Ubuntu 18.10 host)
- `rh-python36` installed
- `rh-python36-mod_wsgi-4.5.18-1.el7.x86_64` installed
- python virtual env created at `/var/www/web-virt-env`

**httpd.conf**:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/web-virt-env
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/somewebsite

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName awebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/somewebsite
    WSGIDaemonProcess somewebsite1 python-home=/var/www/web-virt-env
    WSGIProcessGroup somewebsite1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/somewebsite/somewebsite/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/html/somewebsite/somewebsite>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /var/www/html/somewebsite/static
    <Directory /var/www/html/somewebsite/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Expected output:**

I expected that the site would launch when I executed `systemctl start httpd`

I am suspicious that `rh-python36-mod_wsgi-4.5.18-1.el7.x86_64` isn't being "found," but I'm not sure how this is working behind the scenes.

What can I do to work around this? Or at least, which steps should I take next to trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EUREKA!**

I was able to fix the problem by adding the following *before* the `httpd.conf` additions I have displayed in the question (so, just before `WSGIPythonHome /var/www/web-virt-env`):

`LoadModule wsgi_module /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_rh-python36-wsgi.so`

Answer (score 0):

I put it before the virtualhost

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
<VirtualHost 69.16.201.27:443>
     ServerName blue.domain.com
     ....
```

Comment: This is what I have explained in my answer, placing it before the `WSGIPythonHome` line, which is before the `<VirtualHost>` line.

Answer (score 0):

Installing apt package **libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3** helped me

Comment: The question clearly states that it is a CentOS 7 system, so Debian/Ubuntu packages will not help.